# Joomla menu scroll using id and anchor

Tags: javascript, joomla

I'm using Joomla to build my site. I have a concertina menu and want to scroll down the page when a parent item is clicked to show its child links. I would normally use an anchor on the link with an id on the parent element but I can't add an id on a menu item in Joomla.

Does anyone know if its possible to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it will be possible. You will have to go about editing `modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php`

Comment: Could you please elaborate? For the record i'm using Joomla 2.5